# How to make a jax-rs end point accept any type of http request?

Tags: http, jax-rs, resteasy

The title says it all.

Is there any request type annotation to do that?

Or is it enough to annotate the method with all the required types like @POST, @GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, you can annotate a method with `@OPTIONS`, `@HEAD`, `@GET`, `@POST`, `@PUT`, `@DELETE` and the resource method should be called on all of these methods.

Long answer:

**You should not!** Every HTTP method has it's semantic. A `@GET` is a 'safe' method because it is intended for reading a resource. `@POST` and `@DELETE` for instance are 'unsafe' because they change the state of a resource.

The web works because people follow these rules. A web-crawler knows that he can safely do a `@GET` on every URI he knows. He would never do a `@DELETE` on a URI. If your method changes something on a `@GET` you might get problems.

Find more answers why you should not here: [Rest Services conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440233).