# JSON object imparting partial NULL values when passed to POJO thorugh AJAX POST?

Tags: java, ajax, rest, pojo, restful-url

I have an `AJAX` call in my `javascript` as -

```
var obj = { 
CAEVCode:"TEST2",
CAEVName:"TriggerRedemption",
DateofReceipt:"YAHOO",
LogReference:"test1"
}

var obj1=JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
    url:'./webapi/input/post',
    type: 'POST',
    data:obj1,
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
        var values = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(values);
    },
    error:function(xhr,textstatus,errorthrown){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(textstatus);
        alert(errorthrown);
    }
},'json');
```

When the `JavaScript` gets invoked and the `AJAX` call is made, my object gets sent across (`POST`) to the following `URL -> ./webapi/input/post`  using `RESTFul Web Services`, the corresponding `InputResponse` Class that I have is as follows -

```
@Path("/input")
public class InputResponse {
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    InputService inputservice = new InputService();
    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Input postInputRecord(Input obj) throws SQLException, ParseException{
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));

        String CAEVCode=obj.getCAEVCode();
        String CAEVName=obj.getCAEVName();
        String DateOfReceipt =obj.getDateofReceipt();
        String LogReference=obj.getLogReference();
        addUser(new Input(LogReference,CAEVCode,CAEVName,DateOfReceipt));

    return obj;
    }


    public Input addUser(Input input) throws SQLException{
        return inputservice.addUsers(input);
    }
```

Next up, My `POJO` is as follows -

```
    @XmlRootElement
public class Input {       
    private String CAEVCode;
    private String CAEVName;
    private String DateofReceipt;
    private String LogReference;

        public Input() { } 
        public Input(String logReference, String cAEVCode, String cAEVName,
                String dateofReceipt ) {
            super();
            LogReference = logReference;
            CAEVCode = cAEVCode;
            CAEVName = cAEVName;
            DateofReceipt = dateofReceipt;
        }
public String getLogReference() {
            return LogReference;
        }public void setLogReference(String logReference) {
            LogReference = logReference;
        }public String getCAEVCode() {
            return CAEVCode;
        }public void setCAEVCode(String cAEVCode) {
            CAEVCode = cAEVCode;
        }public String getCAEVName() {
            return CAEVName;
        }public void setCAEVName(String cAEVName) {
            CAEVName = cAEVName;
        }public String getDateofReceipt() {
            return DateofReceipt;
        }public void setDateofReceipt(String dateofReceipt) {
            DateofReceipt = dateofReceipt;
        }
}
```

The issue is that, when I run my page, the `JavasScript` object is sent successfully with the help of the `AJAX` call to the `InputResponse` class but not all the values comes over. 2 Values come null, and the other's come proper. I have tried debugging it all morning but no help. I also have another piece of code for a similar business logic that happens to be working just fine. I have also happened to try out other forms of `AJAX` calls to get along with the same, but I am still in vain. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with the naming convention of the properties. You need to be careful with abbreviations when depending on the default deserialization. You can override the default behavior by specifying annotations with the desired name on the property. For example, if you are using Jackson, you can add `JsonProperty("..")`

```
@JsonProperty("LogReference")
public String getLogReference() { return LogReference; }
@JsonProperty("CAEVCode")
public String getCAEVCode() { return CAEVCode; }
@JsonProperty("CAEVName")
public String getCAEVName() { return CAEVName; }
@JsonProperty("DateofReceipt")
public String getDateofReceipt() { return DateofReceipt; }
```

You could also use `@XmlElement(name = "")` instead of `@JsonProperty` if you have JAXB annotation suport.